# How to pull the utm_source value from the google analytics pixel?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, utm

I am required to store _utm values in a separate database.  I have partially solved the issue by pulling these values from the URL string.  Unfortunately, there are instances where the values are NOT contained in the URL string.  For example:

 - Click a link posted on Reddit

 - Opens a blog on our company website, with no utm in the URL

 - User clicks a landing page link from the blog and completes a goal

 - GA stores the Source / Medium for this instance as 'reddit.com / referral'


How can I use Javascript to access this value (which I think is part of the google analytics pixel)?

`ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-YY', 'auto');
ga(function(tracker) {
    console.log("referrer: " + tracker.get('referrer'));
});`

Using the example scenario and the sample code above:

 - This results in the URL of the blog (last touch?)

 - I need to get the value of reddit (first touch?)

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: If it helps, the Request URL on the google pixel contains the information I need as a Query String parameter.

Comment: Do you need to store this for every single hit (pageview), or just when the user lands on your site?